# Why Json is invalid? (ios)

Tags: ios, json

"body" is invalid when validate JSON. I have print out the properties for "body". please see below the screenshot.[image]

Comment: try to convert it with `+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options: (NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error` and evaluate the error object.

Comment: I'm wondering why some strings show as `"string"` and others as `@"string"`.

Comment: I'm with @trojanfoe on this, what values did you use for `username` and `datatype`? Something's not right with them.

Comment: This the code that sets value for "body". The part that is commented out set the value for "name" and "groupname" literally and it works. It is because of the @"string" value for some properties, they don't work.

I don't know how to fix it. You can see the "name" comes from the text of a textView and the "groupname" comes from the segue. In the previous screen, groupname was read from the selected cell in a tableview and set to the current screen in the segue.

Looks like I did not do it right when getting text from fields

Comment: let name = textView.text             

        let item = CDTMutableDocumentRevision()           

        item.setBody([Utilities.instance.DATATYPE_FIELD : DATATYPE_VALUE,
                            NAME_FIELD : name!,
                            PRIORITY_FIELD : NSNumber(integer: priority),
                            GROUP_FIELD : self.groupName,
                            USER_FIELD : self.userName,
                            CREATIONTIME_FIELD : NSDate()])

Comment: @ZhengXie `name` looks fine in your screenshot. What are the types of the values for `username` and `datatype`? Your code shows `DATATYPE_VALUE` and `self.userName` as the values, but what are the types?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem is on the "creationtime". when I change its value from `NSDate()` to

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

It worked.

Comment: If you are sending this to a server, find out what format the server expects. The standard is converting dates into strings in RFC 3339 format. No good converting to JSON if the receiver cannot read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jsonlint.com to validate json.